# trying to optimize sql query by adding foreign key to model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to optimize a sql query that is currently using a join and slowing things down.  Right now, an account can have many users and users can have many sales. Instead of getting the account on a sale by using join with users, I want to store the account_id on the sale. I can see that the account_id is correctly showing up now on a sale, but it is nil.

Here is the migration:

```
  def change
    add_reference :bids, :account, type: :integer, after: :user_id, foreign_key: true
  end
```

user model:

```
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :sales
```

account model:

```
  has_many :users,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sales, through: :users
```

sale model:

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_one :account, through: :user
```

when a new sale is created, it hits the api and I first create the sale

```
   sale = Sale.new(company: item.company, sale_type: params[:sale_type])
```

after some logic of checking user, I place the sale with

```
   sale = item.place_sale!(user, params[:sale_type], params[:amount], params[:note], nil, 
   params[:custom_amount].present?)
```

at this point it's in the item model, where `place_sale!` is defined. I am likely misunderstanding, but I thought because of relations and after running the migration, the account_id would be set on the item. I did try grabbing it in item and bid model but was getting errors. any insight would be appreciated!

update: I was able to get this to work by altering my migration as such:

```
  def change
    add_reference :sales, :account, type: :integer, after: :user_id, foreign_key: {on_delete: :nullify}, index: true
    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE sales JOIN users ON sales.user_id = users.id SET sales.account_id = users.account_id;")
      end
    end
  end
```

I also changed my sale and account model to no longer have relation to each other through users (since sale is now directly linked to account)

Comment: what do you mean by "slowing things down"? What are you measuring that's "slow"?

Comment: @LesNightingill looking at CPU spikes and heavy sql queries

Comment: What are you doing when the "heavy sql queries" are observed? Creating a new sale?

Comment: @LesNightingill yep! I don't see a need to use a join sql query to get account, I want to store account_id on the sale

Comment: What does your join look like? I don't think you are using `has_many_through` in the way you think. If a user belongs to an account, then that user has an account_id, and if the sale belongs to user, the sale has a user_id. You can add an account_id to the sale, but you will have to probably set that manually in the save. But I think that just having the normal Account -> User -> Sale relation should work fine. I would just `.includes()` to do the query. But you'll need to share your query for me to try an answer.

Comment: *trying to optimize sql query by adding foreign key to model* Foreign key cannot effect on the query execution. Because FK is a rule. From the other side, when FK creation results in some index creation then this may improve. But you may create suitable index w/o FK creation..

Comment: @Beartech here is the query that was being executed: ```SELECT `sales` . `store_id` FROM `sales` INNER JOIN `users` ON `sales` . `user_id` = `users` . `id` WHERE `users` . `account_id` = ? AND `sales` . `status` = ?```

Comment: @Beartech also thank you for explaining that relation in regards to ```has_many_through```, I think I need to update this to just ```has_many``` since I am now setting ```account_id``` directly on a sale and will not need to grab it via the user

Comment: Do you mean that a sale will have both a `user_id` and `account_id` for foreign keys? If so, yes that works. Also when you are adding foreign key relations to tables make sure you are actually creating the indexes in the DB. Pretty much every time you have `xxxx_id` as a foreign key, your DB should have an index. This will make queries much faster at the DB level. Also don't ignore `.includes()` for use in queries. It lets Rails do joins that can be more efficient than just regular `joins()`.

Comment: I just saw your comment with the query. For future reference please edit your question to add info, error messages, or code. It is much cleaner and helps people who read it after this.

Comment: And were you doing this query outside of Rails ActiveRecord? Sometimes it's best to go directly to SQL in the DB for complex relations, but are you simply doing: `Sale.joins(:user).where(users: {account_id: some_variable}).pluck(:store_id)` ? And is this possibly an N+1 problem? I would try `Sale.includes(:user).where(user: {account_id: some_variable}).pluck(:store_id)` and see if that works.

Comment: @Beartech sorry about that, wasn't sure best place to put that but I'll keep that in mind. And yes, I pulled that from RDS -- which is where CPU spike was noticed

Answer (score 0):

For performance queries, I need to see the generated SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  For this one:

```
SELECT  `sales` . `store_id`
    FROM  `sales`
    INNER JOIN  `users`  ON `sales` . `user_id` = `users` . `id`
    WHERE  `users` . `account_id` = ?
      AND  `sales` . `status` = ?
```

These indexes may help with performance:

```
users:  INDEX(account_id, id)
sales:  INDEX(user_id, status)
```